# How to save image or file in dropbox xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, components, xamarin, dropbox

I'm trying to save a document in dropbox, I have saved the document on the device. well as save a UIImage in dropbox from my application.

```
    DBError error;

        string ruta = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string rutaarchivo = Path.Combine(ruta,"Geodesia.xml");
        DBPath newPath = DBPath.Root.ChildPath(rutaarchivo);
        DBFile archivo = DBFilesystem.SharedFilesystem.CreateFile (newPath,out error);
```

i'm use this code but only create the file, somebody help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Dropbox API Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFile), `CreateFile` only opens the file. You will need to copy the contents of your other file into it using `WriteContentsOfFile`.

For example:

```
archivo.WriteContentsOfFile(rutaarchivo, false);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, and I found another method i use this code  for image   archivo.WriteData (Image.AsPNG(), out error); and this for file archivo.WriteData (rutaarchivo, out error);  have a nice day!!